# How detect send completed in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, process, mono

Code below is used to create backup is ASP .NET MVC2 application in Linux and windows. On complete, entry should written to log file. This code writes it in process Exit event.

Exit event write is too early: data may not sent to client. How to write to log event if all data is sent? Stream does not have Closed event.

```
public class BackupController : ControllerBase 
    { 
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] 
        public FileStreamResult Backup() 
        { 
            var process = new Process(); 
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Program Files\\PostgreSql\\9.1\\bin\\pg_dump.exe"; 
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
            process.Exited += (sender, e) => 
            { 
                TempData["ExitCode"] = process.ExitCode; 
                // todo: how to write this if all data is sent: 
                Writelog( "Backup has completed" ); 
            }; 
            Server.ScriptTimeout = 1 * 60 * 60; 
            process.Start(); 
            return new FileStreamResult(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream, "application/backup"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using an [asynchronous controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx):

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController
{
    public void IndexAsync()
    {
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Program Files\\PostgreSql\\9.1\\bin\\pg_dump.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var proc = ((Process)sender);
            string result = null;
            if (proc.ExitCode == 0)
            {
                result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }
            else
            {
                result = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            }
            AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = result;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            Writelog("Backup has completed");
        };
        process.Start();
    }

    public ActionResult IndexCompleted(string result)
    {
        return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result), "text/plain");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this in windows, pg_dump never finishes and exited event does not happen. It looks like deadlock occured. How to fix this ?

Comment: Maybe it just takes too long?

Comment: No. I tested in win 7 fast localhost with 8 cpus, database is small. Using my original code it finishes for few seconds. If I add StdError redirection to my original code, simiral issue occurs. I posted this as question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863753/how-to-capture-stderr-of-pg-dump-invoked-from-asp-net-mvc2-controller